# Error while installing the wsl in window 10 by running wsl --install in powershell

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Following error while installing the wsl in window 10 by running **wsl --install** in powershell

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --install
wsl : The term 'wsl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ wsl --install
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (wsl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I opened Powershell in administrator mode and run then following command ** wsl --install **

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution

**Step 1** - Enable the Windows Subsystem for Linux
You must first enable the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" optional feature before installing any Linux distributions on Windows.

Open PowerShell as Administrator (**Start menu > PowerShell > right-click > Run as Administrator**) and enter this command:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
```

[image]

**Step 2** - Restart the window

**Step 3** - Open PowerShell in administrator mode and Run `wsl --install` command

[image]

**Step 4** - Restart the window again